# Prove that $\frac{a^3}{x} + \frac{b^3}{y} + \frac{c^3}{z} \ge \frac{(a+b+c)^3}{3(x+y+z)}$ a,b,c,x,y,z are positive real numbers.

Tags: inequality, contest-math

I stumbled upon it on some olympiad papers. Tried to AM>GM but didn't get any idea to move forward.

Comment: hint: $\frac{a^2}{x}+\frac{b^2}{y} \ge \frac{(a+b)^2}{x+y}$

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But is this a standard inequality? How to prov this 2 variable inequality?

Comment: That was a basic variant of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality (Google it).  You can prove it by clearing denominators and simplifying to $(ay-bx)^2 \ge 0$.  You can easily extend it to more number of terms as well. It is also one that is often very useful.

Answer (score 6):

Holder's Inequality gives:
$$\left( \frac{a^3}x + \frac{b^3}y + \frac{c^3}z \right)(x + y + z)(1+1+1) \ge (a+b+c)^3 $$

Comment: How could this be Holder's inequality?

Comment: @AriefAnbiya It’s an extended version of Holder’s inequality.  You can easily prove this version by doing CS (or Holder) on LHS taking the factors  two at a time and then multiplying the lot.

Comment: What i am doing to prove your inequality is:
$$ a \cdot 1 + b \cdot 1 + c \cdot 1 \le (1 + 1 + 1)^{2/3} (a^{3} + b^{3} + c^{3})^{1/3}  $$
$$ (a+b+c)^{3} \le 9 (a^{3} + b^{3} + c^{3}) = 9 (a^{3} + b^{3} + c^{3}) (x+y+z)/(x+y+z) $$
so now I need to prove
$$ 3 (a^{3} + b^{3} + c^{3})/(x+y+z) \le (\frac{a^{3}}{x} + \frac{b^{3}}{y} + \frac{c^{3}}{z})$$

Comment: Sorry I dont quite understand the "taking the factors two at a time and then multipllying the lot"

Comment: On road now, will detail later if you haven’t worked it out by then.

Comment: I now know the prove by proving first:
$$ (1/p) + (1/q) = 1/r \implies \left(  \sum (a_{i}b_{i})^{r} \right)^{1/r} \le \left( a_{i}^{p} \right)^{1/p} \left( b_{i}^{q} \right)^{1/q} $$

Comment: Typo, should be: $$  \left( \sum (a_{i} b_{i})^{r} \right)^{1/r} \le \left(  \sum a_{i}^{p}\right)^{1/p} \left(  \sum b_{i}^{q}\right)^{1/q} $$

Answer (score 4):

Macavity's way is certainly the most elegant. Here is a way to do it just using Cauchy-Schwarz and AM-GM. Use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to get:

$$(x+y+z)\left(\frac{a^3}{x}+\frac{b^3}{y}+\frac{c^3}{z}\right)\geq (a^{3/2}+b^{3/2}+c^{3/2})^2$$

So to prove your inequality, it suffices to show that

$$ (a^{3/2}+b^{3/2}+c^{3/2})^2 \geq \frac{(a+b+c)^3}{3}$$

which can be proved as follows. It is equivalent to (after expanding):
$$3(a^3+b^3+c^3)+6(a^{3/2}b^{3/2}+b^{3/2}c^{3/2}+c^{3/2}a^{3/2})\geq a^3+b^3+c^3 +3ab(a+b)+3bc(b+c)+3ca(c+a)+6abc$$
In other words, we want to prove:
$$ 2(a^3+b^3+c^3)+6(a^{3/2}b^{3/2}+b^{3/2}c^{3/2}+c^{3/2}a^{3/2})\geq 3ab(a+b)+3bc(b+c)+3ca(c+a)+6abc$$
Now apply AM-GM:
$$a^3+a^{3/2}b^{3/2}+a^{3/2}b^{3/2}\geq 3a^{2}b$$
$$b^3+a^{3/2}b^{3/2}+a^{3/2}b^{3/2}\geq 3ab^2$$
$$b^3+b^{3/2}c^{3/2}+b^{3/2}c^{3/2}\geq 3b^{2}c$$
$$c^3+b^{3/2}c^{3/2}+b^{3/2}c^{3/2}\geq 3bc^2$$
$$c^3+c^{3/2}a^{3/2}+c^{3/2}a^{3/2}\geq 3c^{2}a$$
$$a^3+c^{3/2}a^{3/2}+c^{3/2}a^{3/2}\geq 3ca^2$$
$$2(a^{3/2}b^{3/2}+b^{3/2}c^{3/2}+c^{3/2}a^{3/2})\geq 6abc$$
Now add all of these seven inequalities to get the desired inequality.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But is there any way to prove the question without using any of the already known inequalities? I mean proving the question just from the scratch. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user169248: Technically yes… There is a way to prove it from the scratch. I could go ahead and re-prove the Cauchy-Schwarz (without actually saying it is C-S, but proving the special case) and re-proving AM-GM inequality in the special case of 3 terms. But there would be no point. I think it is more beneficial to master the well-known inequalities first (like Cauchy-Schwarz and AM-GM), and then apply them whenever you need to. You can find proofs of these famous inequalities by a simple Google search.